Why Apache Tailer handle() method always closing the HttpServletResponse?
After searching many articles, I could not find any reason why the HttpServletResponse is closed. I'm using Apache Tailer to read a log file and send those lines as a stream to my rest API. Below are few details about my implementation.
Rest API :
@GetMapping(value = "/tag/{id}/logevents", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public void getTagLogEvents(@PathVariable("id") String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws ApiException {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    tagService.streamLiveLogFile(tagId+".log", response);
}

The tailer listener class TestingLogPublisher.java. I wanted to write these lines to response as a stream.
public class TestingLogPublisher extends TailerListenerAdapter {

    HttpServletResponse response;

    public TestingLogPublisher(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
            try {
                response.getOutputStream().println(line);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

In my service layer I am creating the Tailer as below.
Tailer.builder()
.setFile(myPath.toFile())
.setTailerListener(new TestingLogPublisher(response))
.setDelayDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100L))
.get();

I'm getting the below error, Could anyone please suggest how to write the log lines into HttpServletResponse ?
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to write: Closed
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.handleIOException(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:320) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.write(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:378) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletOutputStream.print(ServletOutputStream.java:86) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletOutputStream.println(ServletOutputStream.java:188) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]

